# What is the best way to implement login system in grails

Tags: java, spring, grails, authentication

I am trying to implement a login system in grails. After little bit of research I found plugins like authentication plugin which provide full login feature. This could also be implemented with spring-security-core plugin.

What would be the best and secure way to develop login system for my eCommerce website.

Answer (score 5):

Spring security is pretty much the de facto standard in the Grails world.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Security](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/spring-security-core) and [Shiro](https://grails.org/plugin/shiro) are the popular login system in Grails.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Shiro would be a best option for you, It is easy to install and works perfectly with Grails. One of the best things about it is the ease of installation, just declare the plugin in your buildConfig.groovy and Grails will do everything for you.